# Loading data into a textbox and then changing it

Tags: html, asp.net

i have made a textbox that gets it's text from a variable linked to a database.

`ee` from class `employee` and `s` from class `general` both work, and the data inside `ee` is correct.

when the page loads, the textbox does show the data inside `ee.Field` but when i change it and click save it doesnt change and doesnt save the new data in my database , i know for sure the the function`s.fieldChange()` works and that for some reason it doesnt get into the `if(field.text!=ee.Field)` (i have checked it using a simple label text change).

here is my html:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="field" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="saveChanges" />
```

my asp.net:

```
    string User;
    Genral s = new Genral ();
    public Employee ee;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User = Session["User"].ToString();
        ee = s.getEmployee(User);
        this.field.Text = ee.Field;
    }


protected void saveChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (field.Text != ee.Field)
        {
            s.fieldChange(User, field.Text);
        }
    }
```

What doesnt it work? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check ispostback property in page load, when you hit save button it first called postback so it replace the value with the old one and your newly inserted data lost.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        User = Session["User"].ToString();
        ee = s.getEmployee(User);
        this.field.Text = ee.Field;
    }
}
```